# Adding dynamic rows in html table react. Unique key prop behaivior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

Trying add dynamic rows in HTML table (React). When, the props are passed on to a different compoment for rendering the table I get a warning `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`
But when the table is rendered in the same component. No warnings!!!

I have looked into other solutions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576332/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-che),  [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65005097/how-to-create-a-dynamic-table-in-react-js-depending-on-keys), In solution [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153873/warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop), the answer says `The key needs to go on the outermost returned element. In your specific case, that means changing this:`. Which I am returning from the row component, but the behaivior is different.

This throws warning

```
<Box>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="20%">
                  Item Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col" width="6%">
                  Rack
                </th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {rowsData.map((data, index) => (
                <Rows index={index} data={data} handleChange={handleChange} />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
        <IconButton
          mt={4}
          variant="pill-add-row"
          type="button"
          icon={<VscAdd />}
          onClick={addTableRows}
        />
      </Box>
```

whereas this does not

```
<Box>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="20%">
                  Item Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col" width="6%">
                  Rack
                </th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {rowsData.map((data, index) => (
                // <Rows index={index} data={data} handleChange={handleChange} />
                <tr key={data.id}>
                  <td>
                    {/* <FormControl isInvalid={errors.iname}> */}
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="iname"
                        value={data.iname}
                        {...register("iname")}
                        onChange={(event) => handleChange(index, event)}
                        // placeholder={data.id}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {/* <FormControl isInvalid={errors.rackno}> */}
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        type="number"
                        name="rackno"
                        width={"240px"}
                        value={data.rackno}
                        {...register("rackno")}
                        onChange={(event) => handleChange(index, event)}
                        // placeholder={data.id}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <IconButton icon={<VscAdd />} variant="pill" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
        <IconButton
          mt={4}
          variant="pill-add-row"
          type="button"
          icon={<VscAdd />}
          onClick={addTableRows}
        />
      </Box>
```

I have used currentTime, nanoid() for `data.id`

Comment: "The outermost returned element" is missing the key prop, which is the <Rows/> element . Give it the key prop and your warnings should be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the word(prop) **index** to **key** as shown below

```
{rowsData.map((data, index) => (
   <Rows key={index} data={data} handleChange={handleChange} />
))}
```